# swift closure cannot override Any

Tags: ios, swift, closures

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I couldn't find any solutions yet. So, my problem is, that is have an event emitter protocol with a function like this:

```
mutating func on(eventName:String, action:((Any?)->())) {
    //..
}
```

And I want to use it to inform the listeners whenever an event is triggered with some information. *Access token for the "login" event for example.*

```
appSessionHadler.on("login") { (weak data: String?) in
    //...
}
```

And than I get an error, that I cannot invoke "on" with that argument list of type. Of course it works with Any:

```
appSessionHadler.on("login") { (weak data: Any?) in
    //...
}
```

Everything conforms to *Any*, so I'm a but confused. Can someone explain this, please!

*I could solve this with a Generic protocol, but it still frustrates me that it does not works like this.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a promise the compiler can't keep. The `on` function is free to call `action` with any kind of data at all. But the function you passed only accepts `String`. What is the system supposed to do if `on` includes the following code (directly or indirectly):

```
action(1)
```

`1` is not a `String`, so type safety would be broken. The compiler can't let you do that.

Another way to think about this is that `on` takes a function of type `F`, and you are passing a *supertype* of `F` rather than a *subtype* of `F`. `String` is a subtype of `Any`. But function parameters work in the reverse order. `(String)->Void` is a supertype of `(Any)->Void`. So this is the same as passing a variable of type `Any` to a function that requires `String`. Formally we say that functions are contravariant in their parameters and covariant in their return values. You can read more on that in [Type Variance in Swift](http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift).

As you suspect, generics are the right answer here. `Any` is almost always the wrong tool. And `Any?` is one of the hardest types to work with in Swift, so I'd definitely avoid that one at all costs. (`Optional` is itself a subtype of `Any`, and Swift has automatic promotion to `Optional`, so it is very common when you have `Any?` to start getting double Optionals and worse.)

Comment: thanks a lot, after thinking it over it's totally clear :) Now it's working like: `mutating func on<T>(eventName:String, action:((T?)->()))`