# Swift generic protocol issue?

Tags: swift, generics, redux, swift-protocols

I'm testing a simple Swift Redux implementation. Could somebody explain why calling 
`store.dispatch(.test)` causes:

```
Could not cast value of type '(Test.AppAction) -> ()' to '(Test.Action) -> ()'.
```

Why it is not possible to cast AppAction to Action?, although AppAction implements Action protocol.

Middleware accepts `(S, Action, (Action) -> Void)`,
I pass it `dispatch(_ action: A)` as the 3rd param. which is a type of `((Action) -> Void)` but it can't accept it.

```
protocol State {}
protocol Action {}

typealias Reducer<S: State, A: Action> = (S, A) -> S
typealias Dispatcher = (Action) -> Void
typealias Middleware<S: State> = (S, Action, @escaping Dispatcher) -> Void

protocol Store: ObservableObject {
   associatedtype S: State
   associatedtype A: Action

   func dispatch(action: A)
}

final class DefaultStore<S: State, A: Action>: ObservableObject {
   @Published private(set) var state: S

   private let reducer: Reducer<S, A>
   private let middlewares: [Middleware<S>]

   init(initialState: S, reducer: @escaping Reducer<S, A>, middlewares: [Middleware<S>] = []) {
      self.state = initialState
      self.reducer = reducer
      self.middlewares = middlewares
   }

   func dispatch(_ action: A) {
      state = reducer(state, action)

      middlewares.forEach { middleware in
         middleware(state, action, dispatch as! Dispatcher)
      }
   }
}

// START

struct AppState: State { }
enum AppAction: Action { // A test action to have smthg. to call
   case test
}

let appReducer: Reducer<AppState, AppAction> = { s, a in s }
let middleware: Middleware<AppState> = { s, a, dispatch in }

var store = DefaultStore(initialState: AppState(), reducer: appReducer, middlewares: [middleware])
store.dispatch(.test)
```

Comment: I've tried on 11.4, it compiles correctly, but it crashes when you call ```store.dispatch(.test)```. Make a command line app in XCode, paste the snippet and run to test.

Comment: You can cast `AppAction` to `Action`, but not `((AppAction)) -> ()` to `((Action) -> ())`. See for example https://medium.com/@aunnnn/covariance-and-contravariance-in-swift-32f3be8610b9.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35700892/1187415: *“Formally we say that functions are contravariant in their parameters and covariant in their return values.”*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @martin-r for clues. After reading @rob-napier answer: "But function parameters work in the reverse order. (String)->Void is a supertype of (Any)->Void" from the links you posted, I rewrote the code to snippet bellow. It might save someone's time dealing with the same problem.

```
protocol State {}
protocol Action {}

typealias Reducer<S: State, A: Action> = (S, A) -> S
typealias Dispatcher<A: Action> = (A) -> Void
typealias Middleware<S: State, A: Action> = (S, A, (A) -> Void) -> Void

protocol Store: ObservableObject {
   associatedtype S: State
   associatedtype A: Action

   func dispatch(action: A)
}

final class DefaultStore<S: State, A: Action>: ObservableObject {
   @Published private(set) var state: S

   private let reducer: Reducer<S, A>
   private let middlewares: [Middleware<S, A>]

   init(initialState: S, reducer: @escaping Reducer<S, A>, middlewares: [Middleware<S, A>] = []) {
      self.state = initialState
      self.reducer = reducer
      self.middlewares = middlewares
   }

   func dispatch(_ action: A) {
      state = reducer(state, action)

      middlewares.forEach { middleware in
         middleware(state, action, dispatch)
      }
   }
}
```